# Problem with SwiftUI and foreach on Xcode playground

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcplayground

i am trying to execute a simple code in SwiftUI but it shows error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
here is a code `

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    let data = (1...100).map { "Item \($0)" }

    let columns = [
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 80))
    ]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: 300)
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me... do you have any other code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems there is a bug with (at least this version) of Playground, when using ForEach. I have the same issue and you can find more details in the CrashLogs of `console`

Check [crashing playground with ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65103447/crashing-playground-with-foreach)

**Workarround**

- Move ContentView to a separate file in Sources of Playground
- Don't forget the public modifiers

```
public struct ContentView: View {

    let data = (1...100).map { "Item \($0)" }

    let columns = [
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 80))
    ]
    
    public init() {}
    
    public var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: 300)
    }
}
```

Comment: great workaround thanks , i hope they fix it in Xcode 12.5 .

Comment: It helped on my side but didn't solve it entirely, the view is staying up a couple of seconds... playground version: Version 3.4.1 (1302.34)

Comment: and then? Out of curiosity 3.4.1 (1302.34) is the Playground App for iPad? or you are using the Playgrounds from Xcode?